# Only select if the main entry is certified

Tags: mysql

Please consider the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE users 
(
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE mashup_x 
(
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    date VARCHAR(255),
    warranty VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    userid VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    mainthread VARCHAR(50),
    certified VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, "John");
INSERT INTO users VALUES (2, "Adam");

INSERT INTO mashup_x
VALUES (1, 1540804136000, 1, 2, 1, 0); /*this is a main entry with sub entries below*/

INSERT INTO mashup_x
VALUES (2, 1540804256000, 1, 1, 1, 1);

INSERT INTO mashup_x
VALUES (3, 1540804256000, 1, 1, 1, 1);

INSERT INTO mashup_x
VALUES (4, 1540804136000, 1, 2, 4, 1); /*this is a main entry with NO sub entry below*/
```

Attempted query:

```
select 
    mashup_x.id as ok, users.name, mashup_x.certified, mashup_x.mainthread 
from 
    mashup_x, users 
where 
    users.id = mashup_x.userid 
    and certified = 1 
    and mashup_x.id != mainthread 
    and (select certified from mashup_x 
         where id = mainthread and id = mashup_x.id and certified = 1) = 1
order by 
    mashup_x.date desc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f3537/1

If main entry is not certified, sub entries should NOT be shown, how do you know they are sub entries? You see that in mainthread column of the subentries which is assigned with the id of the mainentry.

Currently it picks any main entry even if I selected only the one with which has the id same as sub entries mainthread

And as you can see main entry 1 is NOT certified but main entry 4 (which has no sub entries) is , and it still shows the sub entries of main entry 1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will do it now

Comment: I added it now, I hope it is clearer and more simple now

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have cetified `subEntries` of certified `mainEntries` as the result, you can try below code:

```
select mashup_x.id as ok, users.name, mashup_x.certified, mashup_x.mainthread 
from mashup_x left join users on mashup_x.userid = users.id
where mashup_x.mainthread in (
    select mashup_x.id
    from mashup_x
    where mashup_x.certified = 1 and mashup_x.id = mainthread
)
and certified = "1" and mashup_x.id != mainthread
order by mashup_x.date desc
```

as you can see, I try to filter main entries by a subquery in `Where` clause. additionally, please consider that it is better to use standard script for `join`.

Comment: I just checked it on SQLFiddle and it works, both my answer and yours work but since you posted before me I will give you the best answer :) Thanks for the help

Comment: Actuall yours is even better and onpoint of what I wanted, I learned some new things from it as well, this should definitely be used and you did it as simply and near my code as possible, big ups.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, I had to use left joins so this is the solution

```
    SELECT 
      * 
   FROM 
      mashup_x ta
         LEFT JOIN mashup_x Lta 
            ON ta.mainthread = Lta.id
         LEFT JOIN users xa 
            ON xa.id = ta.userid

   WHERE 
           ta.certified = 1 and ta.id != ta.mainthread AND Lta.id = Lta.mainthread
        AND Lta.certified = 1
```

Comment: Please check my answer too. I tried to use `join` once and I think it has better performance when you have large amount of data.

Comment: I will check it once SQLfiddle works again, it loads forever for me.